# How do I run async code in a Python function?

Tags: python, python-3.x, discord.py

So, I have a Python program using discord.py where I am trying to have functions manage different message commands, but when I put the "await" in the function, it gives me a syntax error because it's not in the async. Any way I can get around this?

```
def selectedCommand(message):
    await client.send_message(stuff in here)

@client.event
async def on_message(message):
    selectedCommand(message)

@client.event
async def on_edit_message(message):
    selectedCommand(message)
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to make `selectedCommand` a coroutine (an `async def` function) as well, and then `await` it when it's called:

```
async def selectedCommand(message):
    await client.send_message(stuff in here)

@client.event
async def on_message(message):
    await selectedCommand(message)
```